# Sqrt function in Delphi

Tags: windows, delphi, calculator, sqrt

As an exercise that put myself into, I wanted to design a calculator in Delphi. So, far the sum, subs tract, multiply and divided are pretty much working.

The only function that I have a problem with its with Square Root.

Variables are extended, and I pretty much just convert from String (I'm using two EditBox) to Float

```
var
   Form1: TForm1;
   a, b, r: Extended;

procedure TForm1.SqrtClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
   a  := StrToFloat(Edit1.Text);
   r  := Sqrt(a);
   ShowMessage(FloatToStr(r));
end;
```

Delphi its returning me

> [Error] calc.dpr(72): Missing operator or semicolon.

Comment: @Micha Wiednmann Just did it, and still same error. The line 72 its the R:= Sqrt(a);

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann: No, there is absolutely no need for a semicolon there. Semicolon isn't used to *end* statements, but to *separate* two statements. Hence you don't need a semicolon after the last one in a block.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand  yes , didn't realize :-(

Comment: Please stop using global variables

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem isn't really visible in your snippet above. But since I got psychic powers, I can still tell what is going on here.

You have a button called `sqrt` on your form. Hence, when you write `sqrt` in code, it refers to the button, not to the RTL function.

Solution: Write `System.Sqrt` instead of `Sqrt` (=`Self.Sqrt`, the button), or rename the button.

Comment: @PieterB: You mean the existence of the button named `sqrt`? One hint is the name `SqrtClick` of the procedure, but I actually didn't see that before I posted my answer. Since the OP got the error message `Missing operator or semicolon` on `Sqrt(some number)`, it is obvious that `Sqrt` isn't a function or procedure, but still a valid identifier. Hence, it is most likely an object. And it isn't very far-fetched that a calculator has a button named `sqrt`.